# How do I release my project it was working for a long time using git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Recently I got a new job and the company their app is not on git version control so I it put into git version control but I don't know form which tag should I start (v1.0) or put any number and that it's it, for your information this project is working for two years ago and stable, but now we start to put some changes on it bugs start to rise up, and also I want to know how should I write changelog for that. any advice or recommendation will be good.

Answer (score 2):

Just use "Initial Commit" as your first commit message.  Make sure you write a good `.gitignore` file so that you don't commit generated files, such as object files or executable files.  There are good ones online for each programming language and framework.

After that, just work with `git` the same way you would normally do... make commits often!

It's a good idea to put a tag on every commit that gets released to customers.  If the first version you checked in was released to customers, then also that.

You should use whatever version numbering system they use for customers in your tags.  If there is no release process and everyone just builds it from source, then don't worry about tags.

You also need to get more people to use `git` that work on the code.  Otherwise it will not be very helpful.  Try to find popular tutorials that keep it as simple as possible.

If your project sometimes does "hot fixes" for customer bug reports without releasing all the latest code, then you will need a separate branch for the code that was/will be released, separate from the branch you develop on.  If you are unlucky enough to be on a project where each customer gets their own bug fixes (or even features!!), you will need a separate branch for each customer.

A good way to figure out how many branches you need is to ask developers how many copies of the project they regularly keep on their machine.  That's how many branches you need, minimum.  Once `git` is fully adopted (correctly), no one should need to keep any copies of the project (although that is often a hard sell).